# different log4j.xml when exporting jar from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, log4j, slf4j, m2eclipse

I have problem when export to executable jar.

I'm using maven and slf4j with log4j

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.2</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I added a log4j.xml in /src/java/main (is the same that in generated target folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/media/dlm/log/dlm.log" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <param name="Append" value="false" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] %m %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] %m %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

But when I export from eclipse the log4j.xml is changed for the next one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/tmp/dlm/log4j.log" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <param name="Append" value="false" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %X{service} %X{user} [%c] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %X{service} %X{user} [%c{1}] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I tried using log4j.properties file as appear [here](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-configure-slf4j-with-different.html), but nothing.

Thanks in advance your answers.

Comment: Why do you use Eclipse export and why don't you let Maven build your artefact using `mvn package`?

Comment: Just, I think is simpler than open a terminal and write to command every time. However, I will do it to compare to check if happens the effect.

Comment: Instead of using a terminal you could right click your Eclipse project, choose "Run as" with "Maven install" or "Maven build...". After the first run, you can add the setup to "Run" -> "Organize Favorites" so that it sticks in the menu.

Comment: I didn't know that trick!!. Always,  I have problems compiling with maven although in eclipse run fine. That is main raeson why i prefer export executable with eclipse. Actually, right now I was trying to solve compiling problems with maven.

Comment: Does the log4j configuration file you actually see (as opposed to the one you expect to see) exist anywhere in your workspace? On disk?  Is it generated from a script somewhere?

Comment: I tried to find it, if it is somewhere in workspace, but nothing. I thing, that log4j.xml should be generated from log4j.jar itself (I'm using slf4j-log4j12:1.7.2), because probably eclipse compilation configuration doesn't detect the log4j.xml that I have, but this one it's just a guess.

Comment: I put it in src/main/java

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter I understood that when run an aplicacition with eclipse I was using eclipse options and not maven itself to build my app.  That was the reason log4j.xml probably change. The next solution not resolve why it happens, but resolve the problem and give me a correct way to build my app using 100% maven.

I just need to add some new fields to my pom.xml to make things that eclipse options probably add automatically.

1.-Include xml files:

```
<build>
...
<!-- RECURSOS -->
<resources>
    <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.fxml</include>
        <include>log4j.xml</include>
    </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
...
</build>
```

2.- Executable jar (I have 3 different main classes in same project):

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
      <mainClass>${class.main}</mainClass>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
  <descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
  </descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

3.- Add profiles to select main class:

```
<profiles>
<!-- DLM ANALOG -->
<profile>
  <id>dlmdesktopanalog</id>
  <properties>        
    <class.main>cl.icpdas.dlm.desktop.fx.main.analog.DataLoggerAnalogManager</class.main>
  </properties>
</profile>
<!-- DLM DIGITAL -->
<profile>
  <id>dlmdesktopdigital</id>
  <properties>
    <class.main>cl.icpdas.dlm.desktop.fx.main.digital.DataLoggerDigitalManager</class.main>
  </properties>
</profile>
<!-- DLM EXTRACTOR -->
<profile>
  <id>dlmdesktopextractor</id>
  <properties>
    <class.main>cl.icpdas.dlm.desktop.fx.main.extractor.DataLoggerExtractorManager</class.main>
  </properties>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Finally, I used the next goals make my executable jar.

```
mvn clean package assembly:single -e -P dlmdesktopanalog
```

Anyway, if someone knows where eclipse set log4j.xml and other options when make a exejutable jar or what is reasson why it changes log4j.xml the answers are wellcome as comment.